# How do I restore the audio balance to default?

Tags: ios, audio, defaults, accessibility

On my iPod Touch, I was playing around with the audio balance setting (settings -> general -> accessibility)

How can I reset the balance setting so that it is precisely at the midpoint (i.e. the default)?

[image: iPod Touch settings screenshot]

Comment: Looks similar to mine so I think you hit the middle well enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should automatically snap to midpoint if you manually move it there.

Comment: It doesn’t automatically snap in I can move it side to side over the centerline, and it will stay where it is.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

1. Try you best to move the silder to center.
2. Grab `/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Accessibility.plist` by either jailbreaking or making backup.
3. Find the item named `MasterStereoBalance`. If not found or it's value equals 0, then it was perfectly at the middle. If not, restart from step 1.

References: https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/5hrmvd/question_help_a_hardofhearing_audiophile/